# XAML Parse Exception on project deploy error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception, ildasm

I have a WPF application that works fine on certain platforms and systems, including, of course, the development system, however, it runs into issues on some, but not all, platforms on deploy.  This sounds like an issue with regard to dependencies, of course, but I'm not sure how to track down what/which.
The WERInternalMetadata.xml problem signature shows:

```
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
    <Parameter0>QroLockdownShell.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>559aaa45</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>mscorlib</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>4.0.30319.34209</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>534894cc</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>4527</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>105</Parameter7>
    <Parameter8>System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse</Parameter8>
</ProblemSignatures>
```

When I use ILDASM to look for 105 from Parameter 7, it leads me to this:

```
Method #19 (06000105) 
-------------------------------------------------------
MethodName: get_BackgroundImage (06000105)
Flags     : [Public] [HideBySig] [ReuseSlot] [SpecialName]  (00000886)
    RVA       : 0x00004478
    ImplFlags : [IL] [Managed]  (00000000)
    CallCnvntn: [DEFAULT]
    hasThis 
    ReturnType: Class System.Windows.Media.ImageSource
    No arguments.
    CustomAttribute #1 (0c0000ed)
    -------------------------------------------------------
CustomAttribute Type: 0a00002f
CustomAttributeName:        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute :: instance void.ctor()
Length: 4
Value : 01 00 00 00                                  >                <
ctor args: ()
```

I'm not sure how to make heads or tails of this...I would be very, very thankful for any help!

Comment: First time I see something like this, but... You got some `BackgroundImage` property in your code? Seeing some actual XAML could help.